# Given the grammar, show a derivation tree

Tags: formal-languages

> Given the grammar in the image below I have to show the following

$$
\begin{align*}
& S \to AB \mid λ \\
& A \to aB \\
& B \to Sb \\
\end{align*}
$$

> Show a derivation tree for the string $aabbbb$.
>
> Show a linear derivation (non-graphical, using $\Rightarrow$) for the same string.
>
> Give a verbal description of the language generated by this grammar.  Be as concise and clear as you can.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, been unable to get any help at school, thanks so much!

Comment: What do you know? What have you tried? What got you stuck? Add a little context and your question may get a little more positive attention.